# Fragment not being displayed when called from Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an Activity which prompts the user with a dialog (which is a Fragment) when a button is pressed. When the user presses OK on this dialog/fragment, it takes the user to the Camera app to take a picture. This picture should be stored and passed onto a new Fragment. The new Fragment should be just the picture, and cover the entire screen.

onActivityResult() is called in the Activity to handle actions from the dialog. Here, I try to bring up the Fragment that consists of just the picture.

```
AddChainItemFragment addChainItemFragment = new AddChainItemFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
// imageUri is the URI of the camera image that was just taken
Bitmap chainItem = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
bundle.putParcelable("ChainItem", chainItem); // add image to bundle
addChainItemFragment.setArguments(bundle); // pass bundle to fragment
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.llHomeActivity, addChainItemFragment); // replace activity's layout (linearlayout) with the new fragment
ft.commit();
```

When I run the debugger I can see that the AddChainItemFragment's onCreateView() method is definitely called. The Fragment is simply an ImageView and I set that image to be what was passed into the bundle from the activity. I also included `view.bringToFront()` in onCreateView(). The onCreateView code for this Fragment is here:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bitmap chainItem = getArguments().getParcelable("ChainItem");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_chain_item, container, false);
    ivChainItem = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivChainItem);
    ivChainItem.setImageBitmap(chainItem);
    view.bringToFront();
    return view;
}
```

The Fragment's layout:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ivChainItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="myapp.heisenberg.chainmaker.AddChainItemFragment">
</ImageView>
```

Any idea why the image doesn't show up?

Comment: Idea ? With this much code anyone only can guess . Add Activity layout and sufficient code .

Comment: Is `llHomeActivity` a `LinearLayout`? If so, what else is inside it? A `FragmentTransaction` isn't going to remove any `View`s that don't belong to a `Fragment`, so if you have other `View`s in it, your new `Fragment`'s `View` is possibly being pushed out.

Comment: @MikeM yes it is. Inside it is a ToolBar and DrawerLayout. Didn't know it was possible to replace the Activitys view with the Fragments view without a FragmentTransaction?

Comment: If the `DrawerLayout` is inside that `LinearLayout`, it seems like that's not the `ViewGroup` you want to be putting your `Fragment` in. Don't you want it in the `DrawerLayout`'s main content? That is, the `ViewGroup` inside the `DrawerLayout` other than the drawer `View`.

Comment: I used a LinearLayout to hold the DrawerLayout. This is because I want the toolbar to appear above the the navigation drawer its open. My LinearLayout is a Toolbar and a DrawerLayout (which has other things inside)

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but if the `Toolbar` and `DrawerLayout` are already filling the `LinearLayout`, the `Fragment`'s `View` will be pushed outside of the `LinearLayout`'s bounds when it's added. As mentioned, that `FragmentTransaction` is not going to remove any `View` that does not belong to a `Fragment`. If by "cover the entire screen", you mean the `Toolbar`/`DrawerLayout` should not show, you're going to have to change things. For example, create another `Fragment` to hold the `Toolbar`/`DrawerLayout`, and swap that out with the image `Fragment`, using a `FrameLayout` for the main layout.